# Google Schema Markup - Event Reservation - View Action CTA

Tags: google-schemas

I have an event reservation markup that works. I'm now trying to add a ViewAction but I'm getting a Modify Reservations CTA instead of View Tickets as shown on this page:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/highlights#ticketed_event_reservation

The Modify Reservations CTA appears to be associated with Hotel Reservations, so I'm not sure why this is showing up for my event reservation type. I know the action.name doesn't change the CTA text but it's there to follow the code.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "123456",
      "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME"
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "Michelle Branch",
        "startDate": "2017-07-30 19:00:00.000",
        "location": {
          "@type": "Place",
          "name": "Emos",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "Emos",
            "addressLocality": "Austin",
            "addressRegion": "Texas",
            "postalCode": "-----",
            "addressCountry": "United States"
          }
        }
      },
      "ticketNumber": "123456",
      "numSeats": "1",
        "url": "URLHERE",
      "action": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "target": "URLHERE",
        "url": "URLHERE",
        "name": "View Order"
      },
      "description": "View Order"
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but have you checked this [ViewAction reference](http://schema.org/ViewAction)?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't provide any information on the CTA string that automatically appears.